# Differential forms - order of the differentials?

Tags: differential-forms, orientation

I understand that when using differential forms the order of the differentials matters. For example, $$dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=-dy\wedge dx\wedge dz.$$So, practically, if I get the order wrong, I can end up with the answer having the wrong sign. Is that because when, again for example, $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz$ acts on the standard $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ordered basis $\left(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\right)$ the answer comes out as positive rather than negative, ie$$\left(dx\wedge dy\wedge dz\right)\left(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\right)=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
dx\left(e_{1}\right) & dx\left(e_{2}\right) & dx\left(e_{3}\right)\\
dy\left(e_{1}\right) & dy\left(e_{2}\right) & dy\left(e_{3}\right)\\
dz\left(e_{1}\right) & dz\left(e_{2}\right) & dz\left(e_{3}\right)
\end{array}\right|=\left|\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{array}\right|=1,$$ie plus one, not negative one? I'm guessing that in some way the $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ orientations of the differential form and the ordered basis have to match up?

Comment: Yes. your thoughts are correct. How do you order this one: $dz\wedge  dy\wedge dx$?

Comment: @C.F.G  $dx\wedge dy\wedge dz=-dz\wedge dy\wedge dx$ How does that relate to the standard $\mathbb{R}^{3}$ ordered basis $\left(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\right)$?

Comment: That is same as your way. Just compute $\left(dz\wedge  dy\wedge dx\right)\left(e_{1},e_{2},e_{3}\right)$.

Comment: @C.F.G - would you be willing to expand your comments into a meaningful answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One of the way to see why the exterior product needs to be antisymmetric is to rotate the coordinate system in the plane $xy$ by 90°: $x\to y$, $y\to-x$. However, an elementary area in that plane shouldn't depend on the local coordinates:
$$
dx\wedge dy = (dy)\wedge(−dx) = -dy\wedge dx
$$